# How to Make the Border come in to a certain coordinate

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map and on some maps that i have seen the border like at the edge of thee world is confining a certain space so you cannot leave the area what would i do to make that happen in my map to close players into a certain space?

Comment: I'm flagging this as "too broad", because it shows zero effort of searching for a solution yourself.

Comment: @Fabian Lack of effort is a reason to downvote a question, not to close it.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer [This answer](meta.stackexchange.com/a/226687/353011) recommends that flag. When you click on the `minecraft-commands` tag, you can see that the last 50 questions have an average score of -1.22. I want to change this and that mainly means filtering out zero research questions like this.

Comment: @Fabian The answer you linked is not from our meta, has a grand total of 1 upvote, and is posted on a question that is a duplicate of a question that has accepted [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223482/370674). Please don't flag questions that show little effort, that's not a valid reason.

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably talking about is the **World Border**.

To make the border centered around a block, use the command

```
/worldborder center <x> <z>
```

Then, to set the size of the border that you want you use the command

```
/worldborder set <sizeInBlocks> [timeInSeconds]
```

(Notice the `[timeInSeconds]` attribute. If set to a number it allows you to have the world border actually change its size slowly instead of instantly)

See [World Border](https://minecraft.wiki/w/World_border) on the wiki for more information. It has commands explanation as well.

Comment: This basically amounts to a link only answer, and should be deleted. Think you can flesh it out a little?

Comment: Well, zero research question, basic research answer. But I can surely expand on this.